# How to increase the base address of this string?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I'm trying to get a pointer to the fourth element of this array, but I keep getting type mismatch errors when doing so. What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

```
    int main()
    {
        char str[]="0111010";
        str = str+3;
        printf("%s",str);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: char * ptr  = str+3;
 printf("%s",ptr);

Comment: you can not write to the address of an array.... so `str = str+3;` is invalid. You need a new pointer for this. `char * str2 = str + 3;` or directly `printf("%s",str+3);` If it just the print you want

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
str = str + 3;
```

isn't legal C code. In C, you can't assign one array variable to another. (There's no fundamental reason why the language couldn't have made this work; it's just not supported.)

That being said, the expression `str + 3` is a perfectly legal expression that results in a pointer to the third (zero-indexed) element of the array. You could either print it by writing

```
printf("%s\n", str + 3);
```

or by writing

```
char* midPtr = str + 3;
printf("%s\n", midPtr);
```

Either approach works. That first one is probably easier if you just need to do this once, and the second one is a bit easier if you plan on using that pointer more than once.

Comment: *There's no fundamental reason why the language couldn't have made this work* - isn't avoiding an extra indirection a valid reason?

Comment: Oh absolutely. The comment was aimed more at "it's possible to envision a language where this works" rather than "silly C, you aren't designed well."